# In what scenario IIS respond with 304 response code

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am working in an ASP.NET MVC(3) application. Its an ordering system. When I add the product in the 'select product' page, It will redirect to 'Review and Apply' page to review the cart.

Lets say I add Product 'A' in Select Product page and Moving to Review and Apply and coming back to Select Product Page and remvoe the product and adding Product 'B'. When I move to Review and Apply page, I am seeing only Product A. When I inspect this by using the network tab of IE, it says that server respond with status code 304, hence client uses the cached page.

How to fix this issue, so that server send a new page to me instead of 304.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an output cache attribute to your controller or action.  I recommend you use a cache profile in your web.config to achieve this.

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "NoCache")]
public class MyController : Controller
{

}
```

This would go in your web.config under the system.web element.

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <clear />
      <add name="NoCache" varyByParam="None" location="ServerAndClient" noStore="true" duration="0" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Now one thing that's tricky is with the newer versions of MVC (3 and 4) you will get an "**InvalidOperationException:** Duration must be a positive number" if you apply a cache profile on a child action (i.e. if you use @Html.RenderAction).  So if your action is called this way you will not be able to use the OutputCache attribute on it.  Instead use the OutputCache attribute on the parent action that will render the child action.

Example:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile="NoCache")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult ChildAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```